# discord.js bot messages and responses sometimes work sometimes doesn't

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot respond with multiple words. I have set it to respond to 30+ words. Sometimes it will respond, sometimes it doesn't and some words it will respond with, some it doesn't. I don't get what the problem is?

Below is a snippet of my code:

```js
const test1 = '`test 123`';
const test2 = '`test 456`';


bot.on("message", function (message) {

  if (message.content.includes(test1)) {

    message.channel.send('hello');
  }

  if (message.content.includes(test2)) {


    message.channel.send('goodbye');

  }
```

Comment: I tried your given code and it always sends the correct messages. You'll need to supply more context for anyone to be able to identify the problem.

Comment: You also need to add full stops/periods in your question. I know english isn't everyone's first language, and I understand that it's one of the hardest to learn, but if you put more effort into making your question grammatically correct, then it will be much easier to read and understand. If your question is easier to understand, you are going to be more likely to get good answers.